# Asyncpostback using standard button

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

Using an update panel I am attempting to perform an Async postback with a standard html button.

I have tried this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="MyUpdatePanel">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnMyButton" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
       <button runat="server" id="btnMyButton">ASyncPostBack</button>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

AND

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="MyUpdatePanel">
    <Triggers>
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
       <button runat="server" id="btnMyButton">ASyncPostBack</button>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>


AsyncPostBackTrigger trigger = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
trigger.ControlID = MyControl.ID;
trigger.EventName = "Click";
MyUpdatePanel.Triggers.Add(trigger);
```

Judging by my scriptmanager `IsInAsyncPostBack` value nether of these solutions seem to work.

I am not using a standard ASP.NET button because of issues that jQuery has with it and I am aware that I could put a hidden ASP.NET button inside the page and trigger that but am hoping for a better solution.

Comment: please elaborate these points. which asp.net version are you using and what specific problems does asp:Button have with jQuery?

Comment: jQuery will not render ASP.NET buttons correctly when they do not have the text property specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event name should be `EventName="onserverclick"` instead `EventName="Click"`

Answer (score 1):

Just to update others, its now works as `EventName="serverclick"`